# Unzip Zip Files in Directory

Tags: powershell

I have a directory with some subdirectorys. I can see the files in the directory with "gci -Recurse *| %{ write-host $_}". Inside this given list there are some zip-files. I would like to uncompress these zip-files into a directory called like the zip-file while using "Expand-Archive".

How can I combine the call "gci -Recurse *| %{ write-host $_}" with "Expand-Archive".

Comment: take a look at what `%` is an alias for. [*grin*] you can put many different commands in the scriptblock that for it.

Answer (score 0):

try this - it'll find any `.zip` files in the folder `c:\foo` and below and expand them into a sub folder named with the same name as the zip:

```
gci -Recurse -File c:\foo |? Extension -eq '.zip' |% { Expand-Archive $_.FullName -DestinationPath (join-path $_.Directory $_.BaseName) }
```

Comment: Is it possible to customize the join-path in kind of the following " (join-path $_.Directory "unzip" $_.BaseName) }". In that use I get an error message.

Comment: Hi, `Join-Path` only takes two arguments.  You could just replace the that entire expression: `-DestinationPath "$($_.Directory)\Unzipped $($_.BaseName)"`